# multiple textboxes one If statement.. Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, if-statement

Hi I want to know if I can check textbox1 textbox2 and textbox3 for null or empty string as one? I have the following exmple I tryed myself but i get an error

```
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Or (TextBox2.Text) Or (TextBox3.Text) Then
        'somthing
    Else
        'somthing else
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox3.Text) Then
'somthing
Else
'somthing else
EndIf
```

Answer (score 2):

You need execute `String.IsNullOrEmpty` on every `Textbox.Text`.

Use logical operator `OrElse`.
If first boolean expression return `True` and `OrElse` used, then other expressions will not be executed, while `Or` operator executes always all sides(expressions).

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) OrElse 
   String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) OrElse 
   String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox3.Text) Then
    'something
Else
    'something else
EndIf
```

Answer (score 0):

That's why the concept of `Function, Params` is there ...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If CheckAllTextBoxsAreEmpty(TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3) Then
        'somthing
    ElseIf CheckAllTextBoxsAreEmpty(TextBox1, TextBox2) Then
        'somthing else
    Else
        'somthing else
    End If
End Sub

Public Function CheckAllTextBoxsAreEmpty(ParamArray txtBoxs() As TextBox) As Boolean
    For Each txtBox As TextBox In txtBoxs
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBox.Text) Then
            Return False
        End If
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```